# How to receive a TCP packet over the internet

Tags: android, networking, tcp

I have a TCP server app running as a separate module in Android Studio. It's listening for a remote TCP packet. The computer the app is running on is currently connected to my local area network.

```
TcpServer server = new TcpServer();
server.listenForPacket();
```

Here is `TcpServer`

```
public class TcpServer {

    private void listenForPacket(){

            try{
                ServerSocket welcomeSocket = 
                    new ServerSocket(Constants.LOCAL_PORT);
                Socket connectionSocket = 
                    welcomeSocket.accept();

                // Pauses thread until packet is received
                BufferedReader packetBuffer =
                        new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                connectionSocket.getInputStream()));

                System.out.print("Packet received");

            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

I also have a seperate app on my phone running a TCP client. The phone has wifi turned off, and should send a packet to the server through its data line, and ultimatly over the internet.

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.sendPacket();
```

Here is `TcpClient`

```
public class TcpClient {

    private void sendTcpPacket(){

        try {

            InetAddress remoteInetAddress =
                    InetAddress.getByName(Constants.PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS);
            InetAddress localInetAddress =
                    InetAddress.getByName(Constants.LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS);

            int remotePort = Constants.FORWARDING_PORT;
            int localPort = Constants.LOCAL_PORT;

            Socket socket =
                    new Socket(remoteInetAddress, 
                        remotePort, localInetAddress, localPort);

            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream =
                    new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            byte[] packet = new byte[1];
            packet[0] = (byte) 255;

            dataOutputStream.write(packet, 0, packet.length);


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The server is however, not receiving the packet sent by the client.

Now, I'm assuming my variables are correct, or are they?

```
InetAddress remoteInetAddress =
        InetAddress.getByName(Constants.PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS);
InetAddress localInetAddress =
        InetAddress.getByName(Constants.LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS);

int remotePort = Constants.FORWARDING_PORT;
int localPort = Constants.LOCAL_PORT;
```

I've also set my forwarding port to forward to the local ip address.

Not sure why the packet isn't coming through. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Pauses thread until packet is received
```

No it doesn't.

```
BufferedReader packetBuffer =
    new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
            connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
```

This just creates a `BufferedReader`. It doesn't do any I/O. If you want to read, you have to call one of the `read()` methods, or maybe `readLine()` if you were sending lines, which you aren't.

Also you aren't closing any sockets. And as you are using a `DataOutputStream` to send, you should use an `InputStream` to receive; or else keep the `BufferedReader` to receive and use a `Writer` to send.